# How to completely uninstall Daedalus from Linux?

Tags: daedalus

What is the most easy and straight-forward way of uninstalling Daedalus from Linux?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Access the terminal and run the following group of commands depending on the instance of Daedalus you want to uninstall.

**Mainnnet**

```
chmod -R +w ~/.daedalus
rm -rf ~/.local/bin/daedalus-mainnet
rm -f ~/.local/share/applications/Daedalus-mainnet.desktop
rm -rf ~/.config/Daedalus\ Mainnet
rm -rf ~/.local/share/Daedalus/mainnet
```

**Flight**

```
chmod -R +w ~/.daedalus
rm -rf ~/.local/bin/daedalus-mainnet_flight
rm -f ~/.local/share/applications/Daedalus-mainnet_flight.desktop
rm -rf ~/.config/Daedalus\ Flight
rm -rf ~/.local/share/Daedalus/mainnet_flight
```

**Testnet**

```
chmod -R +w ~/.daedalus
rm -rf ~/.local/bin/daedalus-testnet
rm -f ~/.local/share/applications/Daedalus-testnet.desktop
rm -rf ~/.config/Daedalus\ Testnet
rm -rf ~/.local/share/Daedalus/testnet
```

**All Networks at once**

```
chmod -R +w ~/.daedalus
rm -rf ~/.local/bin/daedalus* ~/.daedalus
rm -f ~/.local/share/applications/Daedalus*.desktop
rm -rf ~/.config/Daedalus*
rm -rf ~/.local/share/Daedalus
```